# Important question: Can do a very hard problem, 2 months after have no idea how to approach it. Is it Normal?

Tags: soft-question

I have this problem like sometimes I can do a very hard problem (I usually pass hours thinking and then there's this insight and everything opens up and the solution comes up eventually after some work)/ But 2 months after if I approach that same problem then I have no idea;

Is this normal?

When doing exercises should I work to make them or work to make them and be able to make them after 10 years?

Comment: Memory question, this is quite difficult I think to say to you anything useful about that, I worked 8 hours a day during 4 months or more on a book about differential geometry, I went quite deep on that topic the book was 600 pages and read it thouroughly from the beginning till the end and making a lot of the exercises in it. But after 3 months without addressing anything that was related to this topic, I just found myself having forgotten almost everything about it...

Comment: Please don't close this question as it interests the community.

Comment: @incas That's not my problem. I can still remember the details of a course I took 1 year ago. The problem is with the exercises. Also do I need to still be able to do every exercise on a subject like precalculus?